# There are errors in the configuration of this machine

Tags: virtualbox

when I install vagrant and run a command "vagrant up" this is the error message I found! please find me a solution.

****There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:
vm:
* The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found.****